# @Transactional does not rollback in springboot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-transactions

In springboot(1.5.7) using mybatis and mysql(InnoDB), when inserting into database in one method ,some operations succeed and one of them occured data truncation exception.However, the succeeded ones didn't rollback, Why?

Is there anything wrong? I can't find anything in-depth and fully about spring transaction，Do anyone know or have？Thanks!

Here is the main App

```
@SpringBootApplication
@MapperScan("com.demo.dao")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class App {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
     SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
  }
}
```

Here is the service

```
@Service
public class DemoServiceImpl implements DemoService {
  @Autowired
  private DemoMapper demoMapper;

  @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.SUPPORTS,rollbackFor=Exception.class)
  public void addInfo(List<EntityInfo> infos) {
     demoMapper.insert(infos);
  }
}
```

Here is DemoMapper interface

```
public interface DemoMapper {
  void insert(@Param("infos")List<EntityInfo> infos);
}
```

Here is the mapper.xml content

```
<insert id="addInfos" parameterType="java.util.List">
  <foreach collection="infos" item="info" open="" close="" separator=";">   
        INSERT INTO ....
  </foreach>
</insert>
```

Here is the log

```
2017-10-14 19:18:48.501 DEBUG 35894 --- [           main] t.a.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource : Adding transactional method 'com.weiyan.risk.apply.service.impl.CreditServiceImpl.addCreditInfo' with attribute: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; '',-java.lang.Exception
2017-10-14 19:18:48.496 DEBUG 35894 --- [           main] t.a.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource : Adding transactional method 'com.weiyan.risk.apply.service.impl.ApplyServiceImpl.modifyApplyResult' with attribute: PROPAGATION_SUPPORTS,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; '',-java.lang.Exception
2017-10-14 19:19:40.620 TRACE 35894 --- [io-30200-exec-1] .s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager : Initializing transaction synchronization
2017-10-14 19:19:40.620 TRACE 35894 --- [io-30200-exec-1] o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor           : Getting transaction for [com.weiyan.risk.apply.service.impl.CreditServiceImpl.addCreditInfo]
2017-10-14 19:19:40.621  INFO 35894 --- [io-30200-exec-1] c.w.r.apply.aop.InterfaceLogInterceptor  : 请求开始，方法：addInfos
2017-10-14 19:19:40.666 TRACE 35894 --- [io-30200-exec-1] .s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager : Bound value [org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionHolder@5bee83c] for key [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSessionFactory@6a075dde] to thread [http-nio-30200-exec-1]
...some long trace with attributes...
2017-10-14 19:19:40.761  INFO 35894 --- [io-30200-exec-1] 
c.w.r.apply.aop.InterfaceLogInterceptor  : exception: 
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: 
### Error updating database.  Cause: 
com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Data too long for column 'bank_cardno' at row 1
### The error may involve com.weiyan.risk.apply.dao.CreditMapper.addBanks-Inline
....stacktrace....
2017-10-14 19:19:40.763 TRACE 35894 --- [io-30200-exec-1] o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor           : Completing transaction for [com.weiyan.risk.apply.service.impl.CreditServiceImpl.addCreditInfo]
2017-10-14 19:19:40.763 TRACE 35894 --- [io-30200-exec-1] .s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager : Removed value [org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionHolder@5bee83c] for key [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSessionFactory@6a075dde] from thread [http-nio-30200-exec-1]
....
2017-10-14 19:19:40.766 TRACE 35894 --- [io-30200-exec-1] .s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager : Clearing transaction synchronization
```

Comment: what is DemoMapper here? is it any library class , or your own class?

Comment: `@Transactional` with a propagation level of `SUPPORTS` will not start a transaction if one isn't present. Which basically means each time you call this method from a non-transactional method (depending on your ORM) you either get a single transaction per insert or no transaction (and nothing will be persisted). You will need a propagation level of `REQUIRED` to have a single transaction.

Comment: @BhushanUniyal  that is DAO inteface and implements in mybatis way

Comment: @M.Deinum  thanks, that makes sense!

Comment: @M.Deinum method A called by another in one class will not use A's transactional policy(use called policy) ,is that right? Do you have any summary about transaction or know where to find?

Comment: @counterFish can you please show us DemoMapper class

Comment: @BhushanUniyal see the above

Comment: @M.Deinum i have tried, it didn't work use REQUIRED . Does it because spring has handled this Exception (DataIntegrityViolationException)? Neither in the junitTest nor REST http API doesn't work (i mean rollback, all DML sql in that method)

Comment: @BhushanUniyal  what's your concern? M.Deinum's method didn't work so far

Comment: It will take the existing transaction but basically propagation level `SUPPORTS` doesn't care about running in or not in a transaction. If it doesn't work with `@Transactional` either your transaction setup is't working or you must be doing things in a way you aren't describing here.

Comment: @M.Deinum I print the log ，it has transactional .How to upload log file here?Please tell me

Comment: Just add those as code to your question.

Comment: @M.Deinum the outside method dont hava transaction, but this called method has

Comment: No it hasn't due to the `SUPPORTS` if there isn't already a transaction it will not start one.

Comment: @M.Deinum it,s too long

Comment: Post only the relevant snippet.

Comment: @M.Deinum Please help me

Comment: What is your `InterfaceLogInterceptor` doing in the stacktrace? Looks like that is actually destroying proper exception propagation leading to interfering with the tx management.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks too much. It's AOP log, ....with try-catch of proceed....How foolish is me! So, if i want to use Transactional annotation, the service implements must throw any Exception without try-catch

Comment: sorry, reply so slowly, ...firewall...network not well

Comment: You can use try/catch but just make sure that you re-throw the exception from your aspect. You shouldn't swallow it else Springs tx management doesn't see it and will commit instead of rollback.

Comment: @M.Deinum understand. thanks